# Find an object on one of the criteria

Tags: java

What I need to override or to do, to find the object by "Product Name" and the search function can work on an array of my objects, like this `products.FindByName ("Корпус вагона")`

```
public class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Products [] products = new Products[]{
               new Products("Корпус вагона","431-221","20Г1ФЛ",3001.5),
               new Products("Турбина пароперегревателя","131-321","09Х14Н16Б",278.4),
               new Products("Турбинные диски","231-521","10Х11Н20Т3Р",62.7),
               new Products("Компенсационный проводов","431-221","МН16",12.7),
               new Products("Железнодорожная рельса","431-221","М76ВТ",350.1),
       };    

       products.FindByName("products")//Use like this,how it do?    
    }
}

class Products {    
    private String _productName;
    private String _productCode;
    private String _brandMetal;
    private double _weight;
    public Product FindByName(string nameOfProduct)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Iterate over your Array and compare the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 classes: The `Product` class to store the attributes of a single product in fields, and a `Products` class to manage the collection of products.

The `Product` class will have the constructor you've used in the `main` method.

The `Products` class will have two methods: `add(Product)` and `findByName(String)`.

I'll leave it up to you to code this.